# Cannot open a Socket in Event Handler

Tags: java, sockets, user-interface, netbeans

I am trying to build a simple desktop application where the user enters the url in a text field and clicks on the submit button to send the GET request for that page.I am trying to open a socket to connect to the host in the submit button mouse clicek event handeler but the GUI gets stuck. I have to close it from task manager.

```
private void SubmitButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt)  
{

  Socket s = null;  
  String website = URLTextBox.getText();  
  String host = "111.65.23.56";    //this could be any host  
  int port = 80;  

  try  
  {  
   System.out.println("I am opening socket");  
   s = new Socket(host,port);   **// the code stuck here :(**   
   System.out.println("socket opened");  
  }  
  catch(IOException e){ }  

  // and the code follows......  

}
```

please help me out.....

Comment: What do you mean by struck? Did you ping the server and check if its responding?

Comment: yeah sure its responding....and the same code is working if i dont use a GUI...but when i make a GUI and put the code in event handler it does not let me create the new

Comment: Perhaps you show us a stacktrace?

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? Call never returns? Exception is thrown? Something else?

Comment: Call never returns....i have put two print statements before and after the socket opening. the first one gets printed i-e "i am going to open socket" but the second one never gets printed which and the GUI has to be closed from task manager.

Comment: my teacher told me that i have to make a thread to do this socket opening stuff. i cant do it in an event handeler. but i dont know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll almost certainly want to create a separate thread for the Socket code, and most likely using the excellent Socket Selector family of classes:
[Using a Selector to Manage Non-Blocking Sockets](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.nio/NbClient.html)

Comment: I dont know how and where to make a thread. actually i am working on net beans. there are three files, HTTP_Client (where the main function is written), HTTP_ClientView(where i am doing the above stuff in an eventhandler), ans HTTP_AboutBox(I dont know about what this file does)